# My editor_layout_problem - how 2 display different fragments multiple times in scoll- or listview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a Problem, that I could not find in the Internet yet…

My aim is to create a little Texteditor based on the structure of given Elements. Basicly you choose an element out of 3 different Topics (Driving, Eating, Extra Costs) and provide some Information like Time, Adress, Price...  These Elements can be choosen in any order and as often as you want to. No problem so far.

Problem:
What makes it really difficult for me is the desired layout: Everytime you choose one of the above Topics and saved the Information, i want a Fragment to be shown, that displays the given Information.

Is it possible somehow, to use a listview with changing Elements?
Maybe it's better to use a scrollview - but how can i create the needed fragmentcontainers programmaticly when needed, to avoid providing dozens of Dummie-containers, waiting to be filled and displayed?

Please have a look at the Pictures - I hope it makes clear what i want to describe…
https://ibb.co/Kry1mJm

https://ibb.co/26gG4K2

https://ibb.co/1Jvm1Rg

What magic word is the one to search for in the Internet?

I hope someone could help me here - thanks for your patience!

---

This is a more or less creativ Workaround that works fine so far. Does anybody know. if this concept will cause any Problems?
Its the Code of a Custom Adapter for a normal Listview. It chooses what Layout will be inflated, by a Keyword safed in the ArrayList

```
public class EintragAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EintragDH> {
private Context mContext;
private int mResource;

public EintragAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<EintragDH> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mContext = context;
    mResource = resource;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    String Elementtyp = getItem(position).getElementTyp();

    if(Elementtyp.equals("Add")){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editorelement_add,parent,false);
    }

    if (Elementtyp.equals("Abfahrt")){


        String AbfahrtVon = getItem(position).getAbfahrtVon();
        String AbfahrtUhrzeit = getItem(position).getAbfahrtUhrzeit();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editorelement_abfahrt,parent,false);

        TextView tvDatum = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDatum);
        TextView tvAbfahrtVon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAbfahrtVon);
        TextView tvAbfahrtUhrzeit = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAbfahrtUhrzeit);

        tvAbfahrtVon.setText("Abfahrt von Zuhause: " + AbfahrtVon);
        tvAbfahrtUhrzeit.setText("Uhrzeit Abfahrt:\n" + AbfahrtUhrzeit);
    }

    if(Elementtyp.equals("Termin")){
        String TerminUhrzeiten = getItem(position).getTerminUhrzeiten();
        String TerminName = getItem(position).getTerminName();
        String TerminAnschrift = getItem(position).getTerminAnschrift();
        String TerminEinnahme = getItem(position).getTerminEinnahme();

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editorelement_termin,parent,false);

        TextView tvTerminUhrzeiten = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvUhrzeitenTermin);
        TextView tvTerminName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTerminName);
        TextView tvTerminAnschrift = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTerminAnschirft);
        TextView tvTerminEinnahme = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTerminEinnahmen);

        tvTerminUhrzeiten.setText(TerminUhrzeiten);
        tvTerminName.setText(TerminName);
        tvTerminAnschrift.setText(TerminAnschrift);
        tvTerminEinnahme.setText("+ " + TerminEinnahme + "€");
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: you don't need to use fragments for multiple type, use `recyclerview's`  `itemtype` to recognize which view you want to display

Comment: Thank u for your awnser! I think thats the Kind of magicword I was looking for :-)

Comment: did the itemtype solve your problem?

Comment: It is difficult for me, to find useful tutorials about multiple items in a recyclerview (i'm not a professional programmer...) so after some time I tried something else:
What do you think about using a normal listview with following concept: (Code will be below): I creat that listview as normal, but will choose within the Adapter what kind of Layout shall be inflated by the text of a keyvariable

It works but I don't know if this kind of hack will cause any problems later… what do u think?